# How to filter data in mySQL query based on timestamp?

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch data of last 1 hour from mySQL database. I can certainly do it in java after results have been fetched but i don't want to unnecessarily put load on application. Please help.

Comment: Do you have any DATETIME field in DB that you can query?

Comment: Maybe structure of your data could help ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from tb_data
where createdtime > ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR)
```

Comment: OP was looking for records within the past hour.  The posted code will retrieve records in the last 3 hours.

Comment: my testing query mistake - i have no fresh data within 3 hours

Answer (score 0):

If the column is of type `DATE` you can use the `DATE_SUB` function, which substracts a given time interval from a `DATE`.

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [date_column] > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from yourtable where created_at between NOW()  and date_sub(NOW() , interval 1 HOUR)
```